# Circe decoder-encoder for object as json parameter type

Tags: scala, circe, http4s-circe

How to write such a string-encoder decoder for circe?
For example, I have

```
case class Something (s: String, foo: Foo, bar: Bar)
```

where Bar is member of ADT

```
trait Bar
case object A extends Bar
case object B extends Bar
```

where I want to decode my *Something* like

```
{
"s":"smstring",
"foo":{...somefoo...},
"bar":"aaa"//for Bar=A, or "bbb" for Bar=B
}
```

What is the simplest way to organise decoder/encoder for *Something*?

PS May be using derived Something codec + some modification(contramap?)?

Comment: look like I need eMapTry and contramap...

Answer (score 0):

look like I need eMapTry and contramap from String to decoders and encoders of both objects